# Verify if buttons are clicked actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, movieclip, event-listener

I have 9 movieclips, all with their function and i want to show a message after the user clicked on all the movieclips.

EX:

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showText1);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showText2);
button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showText3);

function showText1(e.Event)
{
text1.visible=true;
}

...
```

How do i check if all the buttons are clicked and after that, show a message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function like `test` on each click. In that function do something similar to:

```
function test() {
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (this["text" + i].visible != false) { // do proper check; maybe visible, or maybe some variables - whatever fits your needs
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // do whatever you want here - all are 'clicked';
}
```

Comment: While you have the right idea here, relying on visibility might be a poor execution (the function relies on the visibility always being in sync with the selection, which may not be the case). I would recommend either adding selected buttons to an array and checking the length or adding a "selected" property to each button and checking if that property is true on all buttons

Comment: I truly agree with you, that's why I wrote `do a proper check`. I just gave an example based on the code provided. And I also agree putting this information in object/array is a good idea! :)

Comment: Woops. I completely missed your comment in there. Sorry about that.